# Can this function be improved?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have come up with the following function which works as it should:

```
bool CChristianLifeMinistryStudentMaterialDlg::EncodeText(HWND hWnd, CString strCode)
{
    bool bHandled = false;

    map<HWND, CComboBox*> mapControls;
    map<HWND, CString*> mapControlsText;

    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment1.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment1);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment2.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment2);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment3.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment3);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment4.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment4);

    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment1.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment1);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment2.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment2);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment3.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment3);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment4.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment4);

    if (mapControls.find(::GetParent(hWnd)) != mapControls.end())
    {
        UpdateData(TRUE);
        DWORD dwSel = mapControls[::GetParent(hWnd)]->GetEditSel();

        CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::EncodeText(*mapControlsText[::GetParent(hWnd)],
                                                    strCode, LOWORD(dwSel), HIWORD(dwSel));
        UpdateData(FALSE);

        bHandled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        map<HWND, CEdit*> mapControls;
        map<HWND, CString*> mapControlsText;

        mapControls.emplace(m_editBibleReading.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editBibleReading);
        mapControls.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoTheme.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editDiscussionVideoTheme);
        mapControls.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial);

        mapControlsText.emplace(m_editBibleReading.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strBibleReading);
        mapControlsText.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoTheme.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strDiscussionVideoTheme);
        mapControlsText.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strDiscussionVideoMaterial);

        if (mapControls.find(hWnd) != mapControls.end())
        {
            UpdateData(TRUE);
            DWORD dwSel = mapControls[hWnd]->GetSel();

            CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::EncodeText(*mapControlsText[hWnd],
                                                        strCode, LOWORD(dwSel), HIWORD(dwSel));
            UpdateData(FALSE);

            bHandled = true;
        }
    }

    return bHandled;
}
```

The code is straight forward to follow. But as you can see I have to potentially deal with either a comb box edit control or regular edit control. As a result, I have two sets of similar code.

Is it possible to consolidate some of this code without overcomplicating it too much? My project is set to the ISO C++ 17 Standard if that helps.

---

### Update

Initially I thought I would try a single map of `CWnd*` pointers. But then I had the two problems of `CComboBox` verses `CEdit`.

`CComboBox` uses:

- `::GetParent(hWnd)`
- `GetEditSel()`

`CEdit` uses:

- `hWnd`
- `GetSel()`

By using a single list of `CWnd*` I no longer know which is a combo or a edit control.
—-

## Update

The core problem I would like to solve is to have a single loop rather than the two.

Comment: Can you extract the core problem you are trying to solve, ideally into a 2-liner you\d want to turn into a 1-liner?

Comment: @IInspectable Please see updated question - if it helps.

Comment: That looks like you want to run a single algorithm across data with heterogeneous interfaces. A standard solution for a situation like that are templates. There are many ways to do this. Here's a rough sketch on how to 'homogenize' selection retrieval: `template<typename T> DWORD get_sel(T* ctrl) { return ctrl->GetSel(); }` plus a specialization: `template<> DWORD get_sel(CComboBox* ctrl) { return ctrl->GetEditSel(); }`. Assuming that type information is statically available, this will select the correct implementation based on its argument's type. This is meant as inspiration only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to one of the answers (@vlad-feinstein):

> all `HWND` handles are **unique** system-wide

I decided that I could take a much simpler approach to simplifying my code:

```
bool CChristianLifeMinistryStudentMaterialDlg::EncodeText(HWND hWnd, CString strCode)
{
    map<HWND, CWnd*> mapControls; // Use generic CWnd pointers
    map<HWND, CString*> mapControlsText;

    // Lookup map of controls
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment1.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment1);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment2.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment2);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment3.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment3);
    mapControls.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment4.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_cbMaterialAssignment4);
    mapControls.emplace(m_editBibleReading.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editBibleReading);
    mapControls.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoTheme.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editDiscussionVideoTheme);
    mapControls.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial);

    // Lookup map of text values
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment1.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment1);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment2.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment2);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment3.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment3);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_cbMaterialAssignment4.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strMaterialAssignment4);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_editBibleReading.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strBibleReading);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoTheme.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strDiscussionVideoTheme);
    mapControlsText.emplace(m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial.GetSafeHwnd(), &m_strDiscussionVideoMaterial);

    // Determine if the use clicked on a combo or edit control
    bool bIsComboControl = false;
    HWND hWndToUse = nullptr;
    if (mapControls.find(::GetParent(hWnd)) != mapControls.end())
    {
        bIsComboControl = true;
        hWndToUse = ::GetParent(hWnd);
    }
    else if (mapControls.find(hWnd) != mapControls.end())
        hWndToUse = hWnd;

    if (hWndToUse == nullptr)
        return false;

    // Process
    UpdateData(TRUE);

    // Get the correct selection from the control
    DWORD dwSel = (bIsComboControl) ?
                    ((CComboBox*)mapControls[hWndToUse])->GetEditSel() :
                    ((CEdit*)mapControls[hWndToUse])->GetSel();

    // Encode the text 
    CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::EncodeText(*mapControlsText[hWndToUse],
                                                    strCode, LOWORD(dwSel), HIWORD(dwSel));
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to define an interface to the functionality you need, then a couple of implementations of that functionality. Add in a map to get from an `HWND` to the object you need, and you're off to the races:

```cpp
class Writer {
    virtual DWORD getSel() = 0;
    CString* data;
public:
    Writer(CString *data) : data(data) {}

    void write(CString text) {
        UpdateData(true);
        DWORD selection = getSel();
        CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::EncodeText(*data, text, LOWORD(dwSel), HIWORD(dwSel));
        UpdateData(false);
    }

    virtual ~Writer() = default;
};

class ComboBoxWriter : public writer {
    CWnd *parent;
    DWORD getSel() override { return parent->GetEditSel();  }
public:
    ComboBoxWriter(CComboBox &dest, CString &data) : Writer(&data), parent(dest.GetParent()) {}
};

class EditCtrlWriter : public Writer {
    CEdit *ctrl;
    DWORD getSel() override { return ctrl->GetSel();  }
public:
    EditCtrlWriter(CEdit &ctrl, CString &data) : Writer(&data), ctrl(&ctrl) {}
};

bool CChristianLifeMinistryStudentMaterialDlg::EncodeText(HWND hWnd, CString strCode) {
    static std::map<HWND, Writer*> controls {
        { m_cbMaterialAssignment1.GetSafeHwnd(),        new ComboBoxWriter(&m_cbMaterialAssignment1, &m_strMaterialAssignment1) },
        { m_cbMaterialAssignment2.GetSafeHwnd(),        new ComboBoxWriter(&m_cbMaterialAssignment2, &m_strMaterialAssignment2) },
        { m_cbMaterialAssignment3.GetSafeHwnd(),        new ComboBoxWriter(&m_cbMaterialAssignment3, &m_strMaterialAssignment3) },
        { m_cbMaterialAssignment4.GetSafeHwnd(),        new ComboBoxWriter(&m_cbMaterialAssignment4, &m_strMaterialAssignment4) },
        { m_editBibleReading.GetSafeHwnd(),             new EditCtrlWriter(&m_editBibleReading, &m_strBibleReading) },
        { m_editDiscussionVideoTheme.GetSafeHwnd(),     new EditCtrlWriter(&m_editDiscussionVideoTheme, &m_strDiscussionVideoTheme) },
        { m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial.GetSafeHwnd(),  new EditCtrlWriter(&m_editDiscussionVideoMaterial, &m_strDiscussionVideoMaterial) }
    };

    auto ctrl = controls.find(hwnd);

    if (ctrl == controls.end())
        return false;

    ctrl->second->write(strCode);
    return true;
}
```

This isn't a lot shorter overall (in fact, it's almost the same length), but quite a bit more of that length is boilerplate that's pretty easy to ignore.

Comment: Thanks. But the HWND passed to my function (if combo related) is its edit control. So to find the match for combo handles I had to use GetParent.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Ah, I hadn't noticed that part. I'll give it some thought, but not immediately (I need some sleep).

Answer (score 1):

Your building maps of HWND to MFC controls looks very strange.

Surely MFC already has that map. See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/accessing-run-time-class-information?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thanks for the link to using `IsKindOf` to confirm which type of control the `CWnd` point is. I am using the `HWND` because my dialog class uses `PreTranslateMessage` and intercepts `WM_KEYDOWN` and detects if the letter `B` or `I` and `CTRL` are pressed and if so, runs my method with the `pMsg->hwnd` property. If the user is in the `CEdit` when they use the hotkey then the handle is to that edit control. But if they press the hotkey in the editable combo, then the handle is of the edit control inside the combo control.

Comment: I suppose it would be safe to say that *all* `HWND` values are *unique* in a Windows application? If so, perhaps I could just see if `::GetParent(h)` or `h` are in the map, and if so, then use `IsKindOf` to test the point for being a combo or edit control and then proceed accordingly. I didn't know if that assumption about unique handles was correct.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle all HWND handles are unique system-wide

Comment: Based on your comment I have been able to come up with simplified code (without using `IsKindOf` or templates etc..).